# How can I track a lost DSLR?

Tags: dslr, equipment-protection

I am aware of tracking mechanisms for laptops with a combination of hardware/software solution that help the owner to track lost machines. I was wondering if there is a similar solution for tracking DSLRs? Do any of the GPS modules available for some DSLR models allow you to do this?

Comment: Of interest: http://petapixel.com/2013/03/26/how-i-busted-a-thief-who-tried-to-sell-my-camera-on-craigslist/

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen One determined guy! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: So it is. Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A DSLR doesn't have a cellular or network connection, so there would be no way to have it report it's position.  Some DSLRs include the serial number of the camera body in the EXIF meta data on an image, so if someone posted an image online with that meta data intact, there is a chance it might get indexed by something, but that's a long shot at best.  It's also information that can be easily stripped from images or even permanently altered in the camera.

So no, in short there is no way to track a DSLR camera that is lost or stolen.  At least not a reliable one that can't be easily worked around.

Comment: I have to ask why the downvotes.  My answer is the same as D3C4FF's, just without actually knowing the sites that do it.  It's still something that is easily stripped from an image and if someone knows the camera is stolen or knows what they are doing when they steal it they can strip the information or alter the camera to make the serial number not match up.

Comment: This is really the more realistic, honest answer. I have to concurr, the chances of actually tracking down a lost/stolen DSLR is very remote.

Comment: The only way you might find it is if it was lost rather than stolen and someone found it and decided to use it to not let it go to waste.  Then your chances are pretty good I suppose.

Comment: Its interesting to note that a solution has not been thought of still. I am thinking a lot of photographing amateurs and pros would love to have this feature. But perhaps that is a discussion for another time.

Comment: @Regmi - the problem is that you can only really do it with a connected device.  A camera is by nature not a connected device and doesn't run custom software.  You could put a device in a camera just for that purpose I suppose, but that would be extra weight, battery drain and space that simply aren't worth it.

Comment: More cameras are becoming connected though, so I think it's almost assured that it will be ubiquitous in a few years. Doesn't help the OP at this time and place though.

Comment: I support this answer too, although all of us hopes that on the future, this will be widely possible not only on the camera body but also on other very important accessories, like lens and flash.  Currently, maybe they are some, but very few and still under a beta development, but overall, still it is difficult to track lost dslr since they don't have the network connection.

Comment: With regards to space, a current GPS solution is [35 sq. mm for iPhone 4S](http://www.broadcom.com/products/GPS/GPS-Silicon-Solutions/BCM4750). For battery, one can activate to send out its signals each time the camera is turned on/off (Just an option to save battery). And at least one current solution for laptops is [embedded in BIOS](http://www.absolute.com/en/partners/bios-compatibility). All this is today. So I would not just say not worth it or the solution is not viable.

Comment: @Regmi, yeah, but GPS is useless by itself since it only receives.  To track something, you need a transmitter.  That means an antenna and it means power and it likely means increased noise in the system which could decrease image quality without careful isolation which would be further complexity and weight.  It may still be possible in the future, but I'm not sure there is enough market to be worth the cost, at least in the professional end of the market.

Comment: won't have to wait long for the cries that "the CIA is spying on photographers" when a tracking feature gets built into cameras... I wouldn't want one, not just for that potential (though slim as yet) possibility but the added weight and bulk as well as the decrease in battery life would be too much to pay for being able to be more careless with my stuff. And no, it won't work for stolen cameras as 10 minutes after it gets introduced someone will introduce a kit to remove/disable it which will get quickly adopted by the criminal community.

Comment: Seems like the community is not very interested in the solution. :)

Comment: @Regmi - yeah, just because something is technically possible doesn't always mean there is a market for it. :)  I'm sure we'll start seeing it in more consumer devices and we'll probably start seeing more cellular connected devices like the Samsung Galaxy Camera.  For consumers, easy connectivity to post images fast is a big deal and it's easy to backpack tracking on that.  For the professional, emphasis is on caring for your gear and having it do the job of taking photos.  Anything secondary to that generally isn't going to be well received.  They'd rather have something to increases quality.

Comment: And with the recent government surveillance stories coming out, I guess photographers are better off without. :)

Comment: Is this the wrong time to point out I'm planning on going to the NSA museum/visitor center on Sunday?

Comment: Ha.ha.. A museum should good. I am not sure why would anyone bug those buildings!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, there **are** some ways you can go about this.

There are actually services that pull exif data from sites like flickr and 500px which collect the serial number data embedded in an image you've previously taken.

[Stolen Camera Finder](http://www.stolencamerafinder.com/) needs you to upload an original image to the site in order to do the search. [Camera Trace](http://cameratrace.com/trace) can let you enter the serial number of upload a photo and will search for you as well

If you find any photos from your camera online, its worth while then checking the exif data to see if there's any GPS data stored in it. As it stands however, there's no dedicated GPS/radio tracking available for cameras specifically at this time.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a hopeful answer, however it doesn't really make the facts clear...it is highly unlikely anyone is going to find a lost or stolen DSLR, and even if images are found, actually tracking down the uploader and getting stolen equipment back is a remotely plausible event. You'ed probably have better luck checking lost and found boxes at all the places within a certain number of miles of where the device was lost.

Comment: @jrista agreed, also, if your camera has been stolen, i reccomend stalking ebay/gumtree/craigslist etc and keeping a watchful eye... :)

Comment: LensTag.com is another such service. They have a browser plugin that watches downloaded images for EXIF data containing serial numbers which it uploads to their home base for matching. Kinda well thought out. But as mentioned, GPS tracking has been left as a exercise for future generations of camera makers.

Answer (score 3):

Nikon got a patent this year, to be able to lock cameras just like mobile phones. It should take a while to make it real though.

[Nikon's password protection patent](http://petapixel.com/2013/04/14/nikon-patent-shows-password-protection-for-lensbody-combinations/)

Also [Stolen Camera Finder](http://petapixel.com/2011/04/27/stolen-camera-search-engine-crawls-the-web-for-serial-numbers/) Searches web for serial number. I'm not sure if it's better than Google though.

Comment: Having patent is one thing, coming out with actual products is another!

Comment: @Vivek - true, but it still shows some early interest in the concept.  They are probably trying to follow after Samsung's Galaxy Camera with a cellular connected camera.  It's a natural evolution in a world of increasingly connected consumer devices.

Answer (score 2):

There are external hardware gadgets such as the [Zoombak](http://www.zoombak.com/) that will let you track an object.  The hitch is that once the battery runs out or it's away from an area where mobile service and either satellite or assisted GPS are available, you won't be able to find it.  They're also bulky and obvious enough that the first thing a thief will do is remove it.  A vindictive thief could leave it someplace that would send you on a wild goose chase.

For the price of something like that plus the service, you could just as easily insure it and get it replaced if it disappears.